# Static variable in template class function overwritten by global static variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, static

I have a static variable in a template class function like this :

```
template<class T>
struct builder 
{
    static T* buildOrGet() 
    { 
        static T* built = nullptr;
        if(built == nullptr) built = new T;
        return built;
    }
};
```

and somewhere else in the code a global variable with a constructor.

```
static SomeClass global_var;
```

At first I didn't know what happened but the `built` variable was corrupted at a certain point of the program for no reason. Then, I added a 4-bytes data breakpoint in visual studio on `&built` to see who crushed its memory after `built = new T;`, and in fact it is during the C++ dynamic-initializer when initializing members of `global_var`, in the `SomeClass` constructor.
The code is in a dll, auto loaded by an exe depending on it.
It is like `global_var` memory overlaps `built` memory, which is very weird.

I really don't understand why and how this could happen except a bug in Visual Studio 2015, can you help me ?

Comment: Can you give more details, in particular about SomeClass?
In particular, is there any possibility that an illegal writing operation happens in its constructor?

Comment: in fact `SomeClass` has some data members, and when the data breakpoint was triggered I watched the address of its members for the current instance and one of them was address of `built` + 1, it means the memory occupied by the `global_var` overlaps `built`'s memory. And members are just initialized, they don't overwrite any memory (in assembly the code where breakpoint is triggered matches the initialization of the member : something like :
move rcx this  
mov rcx+28h 0 <- data breakpoint triggered here

Comment: I bet what you describe here is actually not a problem itself but rather a consequence of a memory corruption (that happens somewhere before).

Comment: I don't see how memory corruption is related to static variables because address of static variables never change, and in my case these variables addresses overlap. There is no heap involved here and even If I would have done buffer overflow somewhere by error, their address wouldn't have changed either, only the content at this address would have. But there must be something I miss somewhere...

Comment: @Juicebox: to answer your first point: 1) a static variable may contain a pointer to a dynamically allocated object 2) if you have a statically allocated array of size N and access its N+1th element, you will have memory corruption

Comment: I found the solution but first wanted to clean some points
@Eternal: I agree about these, I was just saying that a static variable has a fixed address stored in the binary, it can hold inside a pointer which i agree can be corrupted, but this is not my case. 

See the real problem and the solution in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : 
In fact I have multiple `global_var` with the same name in different translation units of my dll but they don't have the same type (let's say another has `int` type).

In this case (which is weird to me because they are 'static'), the linker just keep one and use the same memory for all the variables (it kept here the `int` one).

This is where it goes wrong... The SomeClass constructor is still called for the `global_var` I mentioned above but its memory is not `sizeof(SomeClass)`, but `sizeof(int)`, and **this is where the overflow happens**.

To me it's a bug, because the linker should have noticed me about these homonymous variables with different types or/and should have avoid to call a constructor on a variable which doesn't match the constructed memory.

The solution is : never declare two static variable with the same name in different translation units, only one will survive and you cannot guess which one.

Comment: When you declare a static variable in the global scope, what the `static` keyword means is that the variable should not be accessible from other translation units (precisely to avoid naming conflicts). The linker not printing a warning is normal. What I don't get is why only `sizeof(int)` were allocated in the translation unit in which `global_var` is of type `SomeClass`

Comment: This is what I found weird too, but it is the case... when I watch `&global_var` in the debugger I have let's say `0x20`, when I break on it and I enter it's constructor, `this` should be `0x20` right ? But **it's not**, it's like the construction happens somewhere else, not on the `global_var` I watched, and this is where I started to question myself about what optimization happened in the linker... and It seems it "merges" homonymous variable initialization or something like that. Just changing the name solved my problem.